# ShellShock - Unable to update CentOS 5.7

Tags: bash, centos5

```
[user@server1 ~]$ wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5/updates/x86_64/RPMS/bash-3.2-33.el5.1.x86_64.rpm

[user@server1 ~]$ sudo rpm -Uvh bash-3.2-33.el5.1.x86_64.rpm
warning: bash-3.2-33.el5.1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID e8562897
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
        package bash-3.2-33.el5.1.x86_64 is installed

[user@server1 ~]$ exit

[user@server1 ~]$ rpm -q bash
bash-3.2-32.el5
bash-3.2-33.el5.1
[user@server1 ~]$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
[user@server1 ~]$ foo='() { echo not patched; }' bash -c foo
not patched
[user@server1 ~]$
```

Please help....

Comment: Why are you not using yum to install packages?

Comment: Good point on my answer @EEAA.  Deleted.  The RPM you're trying to install was the half-patch that doesn't address the issue fully.

You want to install `http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5/updates/x86_64/RPMS/bash-3.2-33.el5_11.4.x86_64.rpm`.

Comment: I did exit already and logged back in. Still the same. I can't reboot it right now. Yum update bash is not fetching any updates. Anyway I want to fix this manually.. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `yum` to update your system.

```
yum update bash
```

If it tells you 'No packages marked for update' try rebuilding the yum cache then updating:

```
yum clean all
yum makecache fast
yum update bash
```

If that still doesn't work then it might be a problem with the mirror you're using.  Try pointing your yum configuration directly to "mirror.centos.org" in the '/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo' file:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/^mirrorlist=/#mirrorlist=/' -e 's/^#baseurl=/baseurl=/' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
```

**Note**: I'm providing this `sed` command assuming your 'CentOS-Base.repo' file has "baseurl" commented out and that it points to "mirror.centos.org".

Then run `yum clean all`, `yum makecache fast`, and `yum update bash` again.